# How do I sort posts by date and time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm running a toto powered blog and I'm trying to sort posts correctly by date (if I post more than once in a day, the articles get sorted alphabetically for that day). Right now in my config.ru I have the basic setting for the date with `# set :date,      lambda {|now| now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") }` and a setting for time `# set :time,      lambda {|now| now.strftime("at %H:%I%p") }`

In my layout.rhtml articles are sorted like so: `<% articles.select {|a| a[:date] <= Date.today}[0..4].each do |article| %>` I know I need to add the `:time` in there somehow, but have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

Add a field called time to your articles:

```
title: The Wonderful Wizard of Oz
author: Lyman Frank Baum
date: 1900/05/17
time: 12:30:00 PST

Dorothy lived in the midst of the great Kansas prairies, with Uncle Henry,
who was a farmer, and Aunt Em, who was the farmer's wife.
```

Monkey patch the Article class  before the server block:

```
require 'time'

class Article  
  def timestamp
    self[:timestamp] ||= Time.parse("#{self[:date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} #{self[:time]}")
  end
end  

toto = Toto::Server.new do
```

Now in your layout you can use the `timestamp` method for sorting:

```
<% articles.select {|a| a.timestamp <= Time.now}[0..4].each do |article| %>
```